# Tracking filesystem changes / keeping a history of file meta info (Windows)

Tags: windows-7, file-management, backup

I am looking for a software which can keep track of the history of files (filenames, file sizes, optionally hashes; I don't care about actual content changes itself) on local (NTFS) drives. Monitoring could either happen by watching filesystem events or by regular schedule. The purpose is to go hand-in-hand with my backup solution. Because I don't backup everything, sometimes I just need to know what I lost.

So the software should track changes on the filesystem, be able to give me a historical view of my data and answer question like:

- Which files where deleted between date x and date y?
- File x was renamed. What was its previous name?
- How many GB of files are modified per week?

Alternatively if it cannot answer these types of questions, it should store the history in an easily accessible way, so I can write my own analysis scripts.

It should work on Windows 7+ and can be of any format (GUI, CLI, native, Python, some hacky project on github, ...)